# how to move picture from where my perspective onto screen (right description?)

Tags: css

doing a totally new website now. Haven't coded anything yet, just in the research stage. You know how an image will be on your computer or TV screen and it will start to grow bigger, not in a zoom way so much than in a way as if the image was coming towards you? What would you call that? I want to do the reverse, have it appear to be going toward the background on the screen from where I am, so the image will technically be getting smaller but will have kind of a 3D feel, as if it's getting farther away. Can anyone help me with what I should be looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the effect of an responsive image?. Bootstrap makes use of the `<img class="img-responsive" src="...">` to create responsive images. An example down below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Image</h2>
  <p>The .img-responsive class makes the image scale nicely to the parent element (resize the browser window to see the effect):</p>                  
  <img src="cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236"> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`trasnform: scale()` does something like you're describing.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  animation: scale 3s forwards;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

@keyframes scale {
  to {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg">
```